# WPF ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex returns null for existing item

Tags: c#, wpf

**First a brief background**
I want to connect listviewitems inside *different* listviews with lines in a canvas. Therefor I need the position of each `ListViewItem` in the canvas to be able to plot the points of the lines.

**What I've tried**
I've tried a lot of things by now and read through half the internet, but I have not been able to put everything together.

The best result so far is the following code:

```
public class ConnectableListView : ListView
{

    public ConnectableListView() : base()
    {
        this.MouseEnter += this.onMouseEnter;
    }

    private void onMouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            UIElement ItemContainer = this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as UIElement;
            // Get measures and positions from the ItemContainer
        }

    }

}
```

All well so long, but the MouseEnter event is not what I want to bind to in the end, but rather to some event that is triggered when the listbox is loaded. I found that [ItemContainerGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx) has two events called `StatusChanged` and `ItemsChanged`. Some Q&A I've read (Don't remember the reference now) said that these events occurs when the `ListView` is populated with items. As you can see I've implemented the `StatusChanged` event in the code below (I have also tried the `ItemsChanged` event in the same way).

```
public class ConnectableListView : ListView
{

    public ConnectableListView() : base()
    {
        this.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged;
    }

    private void ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            UIElement ItemContainer = this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as UIElement;
            // Get measures and positions from the ItemContainer
        }

    }
}
```

However I don't get `StatusChanged` and `ItemsChanged` to work. When debugging I can see that the listview is populated with listviewitems when inside the `ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged` method but `this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as UIElement` returns null. Why is that, when it works perfectly fine in the MouseOver event?

Comment: ListView probably virtualizes its elements. That means that if an element is not in view the container for it is not yet instantiated so `ContainerFromIndex` returns null. To check this theory first try putting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` on the ListView. This is not the final solution, just to test if virtualization produces this. I had this issue with `ListBox` recently.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When trying this i did discover that each Listbox triggers the `StatusChanged` event several times (Appears to be 4 times during the startup). The first time `containerFromIndex` returns `null` for all items, but subsequent calls does actually return the correct element. This appear to be the behavior regardless if `IsVirtualizing` is set to false or not. I guess I could try to listen to the event until it does not return null, do my processing and then unsubscribe from it.